# std::unordered_set iterators don't appear to be invalidated by rehash

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I was reviewing some old code of mine and I realized that the code was incorrect since it was using `std::unordered_set` iterators across rehashes. To convince myself, I wrote a small C++11 program which tries to re-use iterators after a rehash:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::unordered_set<int> s(5);
  std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>::iterator> its;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    auto it = s.insert(i);
    its.push_back(it.first);
  }
  s.rehash(200);  // force rehash just in case...
  for (auto it : its) {
    std::cout << *it << "\n";
  }
  for (auto it2 = its[0]; it2 != s.end(); it2++) {
    std::cout << *it2 << "\n";
  }
  for (auto it : its) {
    s.erase(it);
  }
  std::cout << s.size() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled this program and was able to run it fine under Valgrind, which is not really what I was expecting. I tried with both g++ (5.4.0) and clang++ (3.8.0) and didn't get any memory error in either case. Could someone explain why? Is it specific to the g++ & clang++ STL implementations which provide additional "guarantees"? Or is there an issue with my test program.

Comment: Looking at some STL code, it seems that older gcc versions were using iterators that stored a pointer to the current bucket (i.e. pointer to the head of the bucket linked list). However, nowadays the hashtable implementation seems to be different: iterators no longer store a pointer to the current bucket and iterator increment is done in constant time independently of the number of empty buckets (my understanding is that each node has a pointer to the next node, even the last node in a bucket). Given that an iterator is now essentially just a node pointer, what I'm observing makes sense.

Comment: Sometimes the result of undefined behavior is that things appear to work. Don't rely on it. If the standard says rehashing can invalidate the iterators, then using those iterators risks bad things happening. The most likely time for this to occur will be a demo to your largest potential customer.